# Help on chat without enough REP

Tags: support, reputation, chat

I don't have enough rep yet to talk on chats but I would like to reply to some answers to help askubuntu.com
Can we have a new channel for users without enough rep? Just to chat about Linux in General?

Comment: I can give you a temporary access. Anything specific you want? Approved edits get you 2 rep, so 5 edits would get you 10 more rep.

Comment: @Seth Thank You, I apreciate but my global question is if we can have an open channel for new users to chat, a #channel not limited by REP.

Comment: Nope, can't do that. Not only is it not in the tools, but it defeats the e purpose of the reputation requirement in the first place.

Comment: I see, thank you then. I will make my best to help then.